# Trouble with JObject.Parse to dynamic type in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, windows-phone-8, json.net

In console app I run the code:

```
string json = "{\"id\": \"5\"}";
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(json);
var id = result.id;
```

And result:

```
id = 5;
```

In Windows Phone 8 with this code I have exception:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
```

I have `Newtonsoft.Json` version 5.0.8.

What could be the problem?

Comment: at which line you getting error?

Comment: in this line var id = result.id; I resolved the problem. In Windows Phone works var id = result["id"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to find your data as result is JObject

so

> `var id = result["id"];`